# Display image patches in python

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib, computer-vision

I'm using a sliding window over my image and want to display the patches of the image that each window "looks at".

I first saved the code here: http://www.johnvinyard.com/blog/?p=268 as `sliding_window.py`, then imported it into this code:

```
from itertools import izip
import numpy as np
import sliding_window as sw
from skimage.viewer import ImageViewer
from skimage import data, io, filter, color, exposure
from PIL import Image        
from scipy.misc import toimage

io.use_plugin('matplotlib')

image1 = color.rgb2gray(io.imread("PATH_TO_MY_IMAGE\\akaria1.jpg"))
window_size = (100,100)
windows = sw.sliding_window(image1, window_size)

# make an image out of these of these sliding window thingies
for w in windows:
        wi = Image.fromarray(w)
        io.imshow(wi)
```

But no images show up. There's no error either. The program just seems to execute without doing anything. I've heard this has something to do with a bug on Windows? What's the fix? Or is there an alternate way of displaying the image patches?

If I print out `w` in the `for` loop above, I do get to see a number of arrays, so I know there's no issue in the `sliding window` part. The problem is whether I'm correctly converting and/or displaying images from the given arrays.

Comment: purely a guess. bit if this `io` is using matplotlib as a plugin. you probably have to call a function to show the figure, as this is the way to do it in matplotlib. Does `io` have a show method? `io.show()`

Comment: Agree with previous comment. If that method does not exist, do `import matplotlib.pyplot as plt` then `plt.show()`

Comment: just tried 
`wi = Image.fromarray(w)  
io.imshow(wi)
io.show() `
and I do get something displayed. But I get a plain black rectangle with x and y axes, that's it. Not the image patches I'm looking for.

Comment: I removed `Image.fromarray()` and put the arrays in directly, and it worked. Can anyone explain why that worked though?

Answer (score 0):

I've figured out the problem.
It looks like I didn't need to insist on creating an image from the arrays generated by the sliding window. Treating them like images the way they were was enough.

```
for w in windows:
        pl.imshow(w) #no need to use Image.fromarray()
        pl.show()
```